# Why gitlab shell runner will use su command

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I want to use shell type gitlab runner，ci job remind me

on vmuatdzsrs01 uvrdzpq6
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: failed to start process: exec: "su": executable file not found in $PATH. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information

I have tried to search the material, but I can't find any relevant information

Comment: Do not post images of text. That is unreadable. Please post text as text.

Comment: But it is hard to copy outside

Comment: Please post your configuration files as text into the question. `user has no su permission` The error is `executable file not found`, not "permission denied" or similar. You are running gitlab-runner _as root_ and then specifying gitlab to change the user.  It is unclear to me are you asking for. Either way, consider using docker.

Comment: OK,Thanks.We found this problem with the root start gitlab-runner service, but it works fine if I run root on the command line. We have to use the shell for security Settings because we need to use a lot of secrets on this machine